# Unusual data from csv using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, enumerate

I have a small script that extracts data from a csv file. the file is unorganised and I have about 1000 of them to get the data from so far so I can't simply edit the format.
I created a script the reads each line one by one skipping all the useless data then reading whats left, I needed to remove the first 36 characters and the last 3. However this prints inacurate data for some reason

My Code

```
import sys
import time
from sys import argv
while True:
    argv1 = "ex.csv"
    script, filename = argv, argv1
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        print (line)[36::3]
        print (i)
    time.sleep(5)
```

My first 2 lines of data are pretty empty so ignoring those here is the next line from ex.csv

```
20/03/2015  10:28:26, 390114.322299, 393732.492744, 0
```

Using the above code when printing (line) I get the data 37.240
I do not understand where it is getting this number from. as far as I understand from what I have been learning its suppose to skip `[start:middle:end]` so it should skip 36 from the start and 3 from the end and non in the middle.

Also not all ranges of data are set at 11 characters so I can't skip all but 11 characters either.

Comment: I manually fixed your indentation; can you verify that it is now correct? Or should the the `time.sleep()` line also be indented?

Comment: You have misunderstood the Python slice notation. I duped this to the canonical post, no need to explain it *again*, but you need to use `[36:-3]` here to remove the first 36 characters, as well as the last 3. Instead of slicing the line, I'd slice the *row* produced by the `csv` module. You can then use `row[1:-1]` to skip the first and last *column*.

Comment: again not sure what :-3 does (i understand what your trying to say it does) but i changed tit to -1 which should remove the last character however it just decided to invert the entire line and read it backwards. im looking into the other question posted to try get a better understanding of this. also im not sure if time() should be indented differently but it works where it is right now.

Comment: Negative numbers are subtracted from the sequence length. `-3` means *three elements from the end of this sequence*.

Comment: i got it. looks like i was putting a colon in the wrong place it should of been [36:-3:] where i was utting [36::-3] and [36:-3]

Comment: `[36:-3]` works and functionally the same thing as `[36:-3:]`; the last colon is optional.